# Return render of elements without wrapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for some way to return children raw without wrapping them in a div, the following doesn't work:

```
render: function () {
  return this.props.children
  )
}
```

This does:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I edit the `children` and provide a new set of children **not** wrapped in another element?

Comment: Have you tried to use a  `<template>` tag as the container? Some other frameworks use that for rendering container-less custom elements.

Comment: `<template>` doesn't work, it wraps everything in a template tag / document fragment.

Comment: I see, thanks for informing me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can manipulate the `this.props.children`:

[top-level-api.html#react.children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children)

And as for providing a set of children not wrapped, it is not possible and unreasonable in Reactjs. You may consider that you are rendering a component, not a list or something. The [official explanation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html) goes like this:

> Note:
>   One limitation: React components can only render a single root node. If you want to return multiple nodes they must be wrapped in a single root.

---

Well, when there is only a single child, you can `return this.props.children` for sure. I re-checked your snippet code and found out you may have a syntax error there, a extra bracket under `return this.props.children`

This is my own test and it render properly:

```
var Test = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return this.props.children
    }
})

React.render(
    <Test><div>hello world</div></Test>,
    document.getElementById("test")
);
```

---

Updated:
In my opinion, you should void doing this as I do above, because I believe this will make your component vulnerable.

Comment: Hey Eric! I hear you loud and clear but if the `children` are already one node, why can it be rendered out? Just as I can render one `<div>` or `<span>` containing other nodes. If I have a `children` variable `children` is already is a single root.

Comment: Then you should use their own render method and don't pass them as props. If you use the children as props for another component this component will wrap them inside it's own block.